# Calling $(document).foundation(); multiple times in Foundation

Tags: angular, dart, zurb-foundation, angular-dart, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using Foundation for the first time and using it inside an existing Angular Dart application.

Is it fine to call `$(document).foundation();` more than once?

In my JS, I have the following:

```
document.addEventListener("onFoundationify", function(event){
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

and then inside my Angular component's Dart code, I call

```
@override
ngAfterContentInit() {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("onFoundationify"));
}
```

So every Dart component fires this event on `ngAfterContentInit` which then calls `$(document).foundation();`

Is there a better way to foundationify an Angular Dart component that just appeared in the DOM or is what I'm doing fine / safe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a cleaner way:

Angular Dart:

```
@override
ngAfterContentInit() {
    new Future.delayed(Duration.ZERO, (){
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("onSetupAccordian"));
    });
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("onSetupAccordian", function (event) {
        new Foundation.Accordion($("element-id-from-event"), {});
    });
</script>
```

This explicitly sets up the specific accordian instead of re-wiring everything.